# Enabling Dynotopo turns my sculpted mesh into a cube

Tags: sculpting

When I enabled the dyntopo as said in the video below , the sculpted face turns into a cube but in the video he is able to sculpt on the face after enabling dynpotopo.
https://youtu.be/WMEXEh5r0G4

Comment: I request anyone to answer my question as I am not able to proceed in my project

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved it by applying modifier in object mode too I know it's kind of silly but I am new to blender